# MacOS keeps asking for notifications permissions

Tags: macos, notifications, permission

I have MacOS version 10.15.6 and each time I launch any app that uses notifications - system keeps asking me for the notifications permissions. Every reboot I have a couple of alerts for the apps that run on startup :(

Tried reinstalling the apps but it does not help and it happens regardless of the app.

Could you please advice?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Does this really affect all apps (also macOS built-in apps like Mail) or only installed apps? In the latter case, does it equally affect apps from the Mac App Store and from other sources?

Comment: Both the AppStore apps and from the other sources. Built-in apps don't ask for permissions.